# trying to implement widget named MultiWaveView from com.android.internal.widget

Tags: java

I`m trying to implement widget named MultiWaveView from com.android.internal.widget
Maybe someone already tried to implement this?

My problem in this class

```
class StateListState extends DrawableContainerState
{
    int[][] mStateSets;
    // Heare error (The constructor DrawableContainer.DrawableContainerState(StateListDrawable.StateListState, StateListDrawable, Resources) is undefined)
    StateListState(StateListState orig, StateListDrawable owner, Resources res)
    {
        super(orig, owner, res );

        if (orig != null) {
            mStateSets = orig.mStateSets;
        } else {
            mStateSets = new int[getChildren().length][];
        }
    }
}
```